# Python Linux unable to press enter key in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, shell, enter

I am running a script for IPV6 certification using the following command.

This script runs and we need to press enter key multiple times to continue the script. But I am unable to press enter key. If someone help me on this it will be very helpful

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['make clean;make "AROPT= -s 2 -e 2" 
ipv6ready_p2_end_node'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for c in iter(lamda: process.stdout.readline(), ''):
  line=c.decode('utf-8')
  sys.stdout.write(line)
  if line.find('press Enter key') != -1 :
    process.communicate(b'\n') #Pressing the Enter key - its not working
```

Comment: Have you looked into [the pexpect library](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ?

Comment: try `process.stdin.write(b'\n')`, communicate will wait till the end.

Comment: It didn't work either

Comment: yeah, I was suspecting that. What works is `process.stdin.write(b'\n'*10); process.stdin.close()`. That will send 10 linefeeds then closes stdin. If you just need less than 10 linefeed that should work.

Comment: Nope. Its not even sending one line feed. I tried removing stdout=subprocess.PIPE . In that case I don't need to press enter key. Automatically its working. But issue is I am trying to write the result in a file. That is not happenig